# Why is day 0 January 0th?

Tags: microsoft-excel

If I format a column with `mmm dd hh:mm:ss` and set a cell's value to `0`, it is displayed as `Jan 00 00:00:00`.

This feels like it contradicts Part 1, Section L.2.16.9.1 of the [ECMA-376 standard](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-376/), which Excel purportedly follows.

From the spec:

> A date that can be interpreted as a numeric value is a serial value. This is made up of a signed integer
> date component and an unsigned fractional time component. Going forward in time, the date
> component of a serial value increases by 1 each day. A serial value represents a UTC date and time, and,
> as such, has no timezone information.
> Three different bases can be used for converting dates into serial values:
>
> - In the 1900 date base system, the lower limit is January 1, -9999 00:00:00, which has serial
>   value -4346018. The upper-limit is December 31, 9999, 23:59:59, which has serial value
>   2,958,465.9999884. The base date for this date base system is December 30, 1899, which has a
>   serial value of 0.
> - In the 1900 backward compatibility date-base system, the lower limit is January 1, 1900,
>   00:00:00, which has serial value 1. The upper limit is December 31, 9999, 23:59:59, which has
>   serial value 2,958,465.9999884. The base date for this date base system is December 31, 1899, which has a serial value of 0.
> - In the 1904 backward compatibility date-base system, the lower limit is January 1, 1904, 00:00:00, which has serial value 0. The upper limit is December 31, 9999, 23:59:59, which has serial value 2,957,003.9999884. The base date for this date base system is January 1, 1904,
>   which has a serial value of 0.

From this, I gather that `0` should be rendered as Dec 30, 1899; Dec 31, 1899; or Jan 1, 1904; depending on which of the above systems is chosen (Excel gives some customizability here). Am I missing something here, or does someone have an explanation for why it deviates from the spec?

I am on version 16.61.1, if that matters.

Comment: for Excel there are no dates before 1900, so `0` = `1900-01-00` and `0.5` = `1900-01-00 12:00:00` if you were to format it with a date,  If only formatting it with time it would return just the `12:00:00` so `0` days has to exist to allow for just time entries.

Comment: Is that the answer then? Excel does not support dates before 1900? I'd appreciate any more info you might have regarding this (Excel documentation, etc.)

Comment: I don't see anything to that effect in [Excel's notes on the topic](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-oe376/db9b9b72-b10b-4e7e-844c-09f88c972219), either

Comment: It is a comment because that is what I have found through years of using Excel.  I do not have back up documentation specifically or I would have "answered" the question with such.  So take my comment as you like.

Comment: It's also shown as a Saturday, when the 1st Jan 1900 was a Monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This feels like it contradicts Part 1, Section L.2.16.9.1 of the ECMA-376 standard
>
> In the 1900 backward compatibility date-base system, the lower limit is January 1, 1900, 00:00:00, which has serial value 1

No, it doesn't contradict this part. Lower limit is serial value 1; serial value 0 is out of limit, is shouldn't be used and you can't expect correct result using it.

I could find this part in [documentation of date function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/date-function-e36c0c8c-4104-49da-ab83-82328b832349):

> Excel interprets the year argument according to the date system your computer is using. By default, Microsoft Excel for Windows uses the 1900 date system, which means the first date is January 1, 1900.